# Sorting ListBox With Multiple Fields By Date

Tags: c#, sorting, date, listbox

I'm writing in C#

I have two list boxes.

List Box 1 gets populated and i have no problems with that.

I then have a foreach loop that goes through each item in List Box 1 and populates list box 2 based off of a linq query.

```
                    foreach (var item in listBox2.Items) 
                    {

                      var date =
                           (from z in task.tblContractProcessRequests
                            where z.RequestID == Int32.Parse(item.ToString()) && z.RequestTypeID == 1
                            select z).Single();

                      listBox3.Items.Add( date.RequestID + " - " + date.RequestTime);

                    }
```

So now my List box 2 looks something like this

```
 12345 - 01/12/2010
 65432 - 03/12/2009
 92354 - 12/31/2013
```

How would i then sort this second list box bay date descending to look like this?

```
 92354 - 12/31/2013
 12345 - 01/12/2010
 65432 - 03/12/2009
```

Comment: You could store the dates in a sorted dictionary then retrieve the value saved using the keyvaluepair and add them to the list box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get an ordered list of dates, then populate listBox3:

```
var dates = listBox2.Items.Cast<object>().Select( item => 
     (from z in task.tblContractProcessRequests
      where z.RequestID == Int32.Parse(item.ToString()) && z.RequestTypeID == 1
      select z).Single() ).OrderByDescending(d => d.RequestTime);


 foreach (var date in dates) 
 {
    listBox3.Items.Add( date.RequestID + " - " + date.RequestTime);
 }
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection does not contain a definition for select is the error on this.

Comment: Add: using System.Linq

Comment: No - create the list of sorted dates up front. The .Cast is something I added just before the .Select.